# Maven ignoring plugin version from pluginManagement in profile of submodule

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml, versions-maven-plugin

I'm defining plugin versions in the `<pluginManagement>` section of a parent POM and want to use them in the `<plugins>` section of submodules.

This is working, unless the plugin is being used inside a profile of a submodule. In this case, the version from the parent POM's `<pluginManagement>` section is ignored.

Output of `mvn -v`:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_102, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

`./pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.1.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <modules>
        <module>project1</module>
    </modules>

    <groupId>org.example.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

`./project1/pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.1.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.example.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>project1</artifactId>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>p1</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Output of `mvn versions:display-plugin-updates`:

```
$ mvn versions:display-plugin-updates
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] test-parent
[INFO] project1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test-parent 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.2:display-plugin-updates (default-cli) @ test-parent ---
[INFO]
[INFO] All plugins with a version specified are using the latest versions.
[INFO]
[INFO] Project defines minimum Maven version as: 3.1.0
[INFO] Plugins require minimum Maven version of: 3.1.0
[INFO] Note: the super-pom from Maven 3.3.9 defines some of the plugin
[INFO]       versions and may be influencing the plugins required minimum Maven
[INFO]       version.
[INFO]
[INFO] No plugins require a newer version of Maven than specified by the pom.
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building project1 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.2:display-plugin-updates (default-cli) @ project1 ---
[INFO]
[INFO] All plugins with a version specified are using the latest versions.
[INFO]
[WARNING] The following plugins do not have their version specified:
[WARNING]   com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin ................. 0.0.26
[INFO]
[INFO] Project defines minimum Maven version as: 3.1.0
[INFO] Plugins require minimum Maven version of: 3.1.0
[INFO] Note: the super-pom from Maven 3.3.9 defines some of the plugin
[INFO]       versions and may be influencing the plugins required minimum Maven
[INFO]       version.
[INFO]
[INFO] No plugins require a newer version of Maven than specified by the pom.
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] test-parent ........................................ SUCCESS [  0.851 s]
[INFO] project1 ........................................... SUCCESS [  0.314 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.649 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-16T16:03:04+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/247M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can duplicate the information from the `<pluginManagement>` section of the parent POM inside the submodules to make it work, but I want to avoid this for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maven is not ignoring it, you can check it by executing the following:

```
mvn -pl project1 help:effective-pom -Doutput=noProfilePom.xml
```

The [`effective-pom`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html) goal will:

> Displays the effective POM as an XML for this build, with the active profiles factored in.

Checking the `noProfilePom.xml` generated, you will see what effectively Maven will run when building the `pom.xml` of the `project1` module.

There we can see:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
      <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
<plugins>
  ...  
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-clean</id>
        <phase>clean</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>clean</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
    ...
</plugins>
```

Hence, the `pluginManagement` has been merged properly (taken from the parent), while the `plugins` section doesn't provide it.

But running the following:

```
mvn -pl project1 -Pp1 help:effective-pom -Doutput=withProfilePom.xml
```

Note: we are also activating the profile via `-Pp1` as part of the goal execution.

As part of the generated `withProfilePom.xml` will have:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
      <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-clean</id>
        <phase>clean</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>clean</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
    ...
</plugins>
```

This time the `p1` profile was active and its has properly injected into the `plugins` section its plugin declaration, taking then its version from the `pluginManagement` of the parent.

Hence: the `pluginManagement` section is not ignored by `plugin`s declared in a profile.

Comment: Then, why is the OP getting the warning "The following plugins do not have their version specified" when running the subproject with profile p1?

Comment: @LittleSanti it might actually be an issue of the `versions-maven-plugin` rather than a Maven issue.

Comment: Looks like you are correct, A_Di_Matteo. Thanks a lot!